# Java lottery game

Tags: java, list, compare

http://pastebin.com/VCV4RUkv

Hey, I'm trying to do a java lottery that asks the user to input 6 numbers, and the computer will randomize numbers between 1-48. It should also tell the user how many of the guesses were correct, and then let the user input more numbers until you guessed all 6 correct, right now my code is not comparing the input numbers to the randomized winning numbers correctly, it will only tell you that you guessed a correct number if the number happens to be in the same slot as the number in the winning numbers are. IE guessednumbers[1,2,3,4,5,6] correctnumbers[14,12,3,18,25,34] = 1 correct guess.
guessednumbers[1,2,3,4,5,6] correctnumbers[14,3,12,18,25,34] = 0
correct guess.

I'm really new to java so any help is appreciated, thanks in advance! /Victor

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to iterate through input array in a for loop, get the value, and then iterate through the winning array inside that in a for loop and check for equality.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
{
    int num = inputArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < winningArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (num == winningArray[j])
        {numMatches++; break;}
    }
}
```